# Problem about controller and dao functions

Tags: spring, controller

i made some small project
there are just add, delete, showlist functions
add and delete functions good work but get list functions are didn't work.
(in my project memoservice.getAll() function didn't work well)
so i try to get lists like this,

```
List <Memo> mem = getAll();
```

but there are no return values;
what's the problem in my project. help me plz!

some codes are here.

MemoController.java

```
package springbook.sug.web;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Provider;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;

import springbook.sug.domain.Memo;
import springbook.sug.service.MemoService;
import springbook.sug.web.security.LoginInfo;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/memo")
public class MemoController {
    @Autowired
    private MemoService memoService;

    private @Inject Provider<LoginInfo> loginInfoProvider;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String list(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute(this.memoService.getAll());
        return "memo/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/list/{userId}")
    public String list(@PathVariable int userId, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute(this.memoService.get(userId));
        return "memo/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{memoId}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable int memoId) {
        this.memoService.delete(memoId);
        return "memo/deleted";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/add/")
    public String showform(ModelMap model) {
        Memo memo = new Memo();
        model.addAttribute(memo);
        return "memo/add";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@ModelAttribute @Valid Memo memo, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "list";
        }
        else {
            this.memoService.add(memo);             
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:list";
        }
    }
}
```

MemoService.java

```
package springbook.sug.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import springbook.sug.dao.MemoDao;
import springbook.sug.domain.Memo;

@Service
@Transactional
public class MemoServiceImpl implements MemoService{
    private MemoDao memoDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setMemoDao(MemoDao memoDao) {
        this.memoDao = memoDao;
    }

    public Memo add(Memo memo) {
        memo.initDates();
        return this.memoDao.add(memo);
    }

    public void delete(int memoId) {
        this.memoDao.delete(memoId);
    }

    public Memo get(int userId) {
        return this.memoDao.get(userId);
    }

    public Memo update(Memo memo) {
        return this.memoDao.update(memo);
    }

    public List<Memo> getAll() {
        return this.memoDao.getAll();
    }
}
```

MemoDao.java

```
package springbook.sug.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.BeanPropertySqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcInsert;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import springbook.sug.domain.Memo;

@Repository
public class MemoDaoJdbc implements MemoDao {
    private SimpleJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcInsert memoInsert;

    private RowMapper<Memo> rowMapper = 
            new RowMapper<Memo>() {
                public Memo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Memo memo = new Memo();
                memo.setMemoId(rs.getInt("memoId"));
                memo.setMemoContents(rs.getString("memoContents"));
                memo.setMemoRegister(rs.getString("memoRegister"));
                memo.setCreated(rs.getDate("created"));

                return memo;
        }
    };

    @Autowired
    public void init(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.memoInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource)
                        .withTableName("memos")
                        .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("memoId");
    }

    public Memo add(Memo memo) {
        int generatedId = this.memoInsert.executeAndReturnKey(
                new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(memo)).intValue();
        memo.setMemoId(generatedId);
        return memo;
    }

    public Memo update(Memo memo) {
        int affected = jdbcTemplate.update(
                "update memos set " +
                "memoContents = :memoContents, " +
                "memoRegister = :memoRegister, " +
                "created = :created, " + 
                "where memoId = :memoId",
                new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(memo));
        return memo;
    }

    public void delete(int memoId) {
        this.jdbcTemplate.update("delete from memos where memoId = ?", memoId);
    }

    public int deleteAll() {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.update("delete from memos");
    }

    public Memo get(int memoId) {
        try {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from memos where memoId = ?", 
                this.rowMapper, memoId);
        }
        catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<Memo> search(String memoRegister) {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.query("select * from memos where memoRegister = ?", 
                this.rowMapper, "%" + memoRegister + "%");
    }

    public List<Memo> getAll() {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.query("select * from memos order by memoId desc", 
                this.rowMapper);
    }

    public long count() {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForLong("select count(0) from memos");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an exception when running the code? If so, stack trace is needed. If not, do you have data in your table to return? How are you injecting datasource into your dao implementation? Your application context might help.

Comment: Thanks you for answer Bobby Fisher. It run well without any exception. And, There are 8 datas in table. In xml, i injected datasource from xml files.

Comment: Add, delete, get(int id) fuction are going well but, In memoService.java, List<Memo> getAll() function is problem...

Comment: In Xml file like this.`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/database.properties"/> <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"> <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClass}" /> <property name="url" value="${database.url}" /> <property name="username" value="${database.username}" /> <property name="password" value="${database.password}" /> </bean>`